# Error while Inserting Clob data in SQLServer with JTDS Driver

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jdbc, jtds

I have a requirement to insert clob data in SQLServer Table.

below Code is throwing `java.lang.AbstractMethodError: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC3.createClob()Ljava/sql/Clob`

```
public void executeQueryWithPreparedStatements(int messageID,String xmlMessage,String xmlDataStorageType) throws SQLException {
        String dataTypeSpecificSQL = "Insert into OXI_MESSAGE_AS_CLOB(messageid,MSG_content) values (?,?)";
        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        try {
            statement = connection.prepareStatement(dataTypeSpecificSQL);
            statement.setInt(1, messageID);

            Clob clobData = connection.createClob();
            clobData.setString(0,xmlMessage);
            statement.setClob(2, clobData);

            statement.executeUpdate();

        }catch(SQLException sqle){
            throw  sqle;
        }finally {
            releaseResource(statement);
        }
    }
```

1. I am using Jtds-1.2.8.jar
2. When I checked the sourcecode I have found that `createClob()` method is not available in `net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC3` class
3. Whether someOne else also faced this issue ?

Please provide suggestion for how to insert clob data with Jtds Driver in SQLServer with this issue?

Comment: The `createClob` method was added in Java 6 / JDBC 4. The JTDS driver doesn't implement JDBC 4, so this method is not available.

Comment: @Mark does it implies that we cannot insert clob data with the help of Jtds Driver then ?

Comment: You can (eg using `setCharacterStream`; the 3 parameter version, as the 2 parameter version was added in Java 6; you might also be able to simply use `setString`), and there probably is a way to create a `Clob` instance with JTDS, but as I don't use JTDS, I don't know for sure (which is also the reason I posted a comment, and not an answer).